# Format list of strings fact when using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a "fact" in my Ansible provisionig similar to below

```
---
- name: Get disks
  set_fact: lvm_disks_present="{{hostvars[inventory_hostname]["ansible_devices"].keys()|list}}"
```

When I "debug" this it shows

```
ok: [proxy] => (item=lvm_disks_present: [u'sdc', u'sdb', u'sda', u'dm-0', u'dm-1']) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "item": "lvm_disks_present: [u'sdc', u'sdb', u'sda', u'dm-0', u'dm-1']"
}
```

I want to append each item with `/dev/` and turn it into

```
[u'/dev/sdc', u'/dev/sdb', u'/dev/sda', u'/dev/dm-0', u'/dev/dm-1']
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *I want to append each item with /dev/ and turn it into*

```
[u'/dev/sdc', u'/dev/sdb', u'/dev/sda', u'/dev/dm-0', u'/dev/dm-1']
```

A: Use *`map`* and [*`regex_replace`*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters). For example

```
- set_fact:
    lvm_disks: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_devices'].keys()|
                   list|
                   map('regex_replace', '(.*)', '/dev/\\1')|
                   list }}"
```